# Can't understand the connect in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use `mongoose` to connect `mongodb` in `nodejs`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testdb", {useNewUrlParser: true});
let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", function (error) {
    console.log("fail--->" + error);
});
db.on("open", function () {
    console.log("connected");
});
```

This works well, and I find another way, and change above code to

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
let db = mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testdb", { useNewUrlParser: true });
db.connection.on("error", function (error) {
    console.log("fail--->" + error);
});
db.connection.on("open", function () {
    console.log("connected");
});
```

But this will throw error

```
db.connection.on("error", function (error) {
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

Can anyone explain for me? And what's the different of the two pieces of codes above, Many thanks.

Comment: What do you expect the `.connect()` to return? And did you read the documentation where this is already explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongoose.connect()` only setup a connection to a database and returns a promise. Mongoose creates default database connection when you call `mongoose.connect()`, this default connection you can access using `mongoose.connection`. Now you can check status of this connection using events like error/open etc.

Your second piece of code is not working because `mongoose.connect()` returns promise not database connection object. You are trying to access **connection** property which is not exists, so throwing error undefined property error.

```
db.connection.on("error", function (error) {
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

Hope this will help you :)

.

Comment: I found that an hour ago, but thank you all the same.